# Using grouper to group a timestamp in a specific range

Tags: pandas, timestamp, pandas-groupby

Suppose that I have a data-frame (DF). Index of this data-frame is timestamp from 11 AM to 6 PM every day and this data-frame contains 30 days. I want to group it every 30 minutes. This is the function I'm using:

```
out = DF.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='30min'))
```

The start date of output is correct, but it considers the whole day (24h) for grouping. For example, In the new timestamp, I have something like this:

```
11:00:00
11:30:00
12:00:00
12:30:00
...
18:00:00
18:30:00
...
23:00:00
23:30:00
...
2:00:00
2:30:00
...
...
10:30:00
11:00:00
11:30:00
```

As a result, many outputs are empty because from 6:00 PM to 11 AM, I don't have any data.

Comment: Can you add some data sample? Can you explain `24h` for grouping if `freq='30min'` ?

Comment: The output is correct and as expected. If you do not want to keep the empty intervals simply filter them away afterwards.

Comment: @JohnSloper Is there any way to handle that in `groupby`?

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution should be [`DatetimeIndex.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.floor.html):

```
out = DF.groupby(DF.index.floor('30min'))
```

Or use `dropna` after aggregate function:

```
out = DF.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='30min')).mean().dropna()
```

Comment: I am using pandas v. 1.1.2 so your answer made my life easier but I see solution in version 1.2.0 from new option: "dropna bool, default True
If True, and if group keys contain NA values, NA values together with row/column will be dropped. If False, NA values will also be treated as the key in groups."

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comment to original post this is as expected. If you want to remove empty groups simply slice them afterwards. Assuming in this case you are using count to aggregate:

```
df = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='30min')).count()
df = df[df > 0]
```